# Turn the front wheels of a car according to the car's bezier path

Tags: 3d, rotation, bezier, direction, derivative

I have a 3D car which follows a predefined 3D Bezier path. I want the car's front wheels' rotation to match the car's changing direction.

I had the idea to match the wheel's orientation to the **derivative of the path's direction** (3D vector), aka the 2nd degree derivative of the Bezier path.

For some reason, this barely works. At some point it seems to work fine, while at others the wheel spins like hell. I noted that the 2nd degree derivative changes even when the Bezier path is a **straight line**: AFAIK in this case it should be **0**.

So, **my 1st question** is if my idea to match the wheel's rotation to the 2nd degree is the way to go. If yes, **my 2nd question** is what on earth is going wrong?

Here is my Bezier 3D curve code:

```
package fanlib.math {

import flash.geom.Vector3D;

public class BezierCubic3D
{
    public const anchor1:Vector3D = new Vector3D();
    public const anchor2:Vector3D = new Vector3D();
    public const control1:Vector3D = new Vector3D();
    public const control2:Vector3D = new Vector3D();
    /**
     * Gets values from both 'getPointAt' and 'getDirectionAt'
     */
    public const result:Vector3D = new Vector3D();
    private const previous:Vector3D = new Vector3D(); // temporary (optimization)

    // normalization aka arc-parameterization
    public var arcLengths:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>;
    public var steps:Number = 100;

    private var _length:Number;

    public function BezierCubic3D()
    {
    }

    /**
     * To get a point between anchor1 and anchor2, pass value [0...1]
     * @param t
     */
    public function getPointAt(t:Number):Vector3D {
        const t2:Number = t*t;
        const t3:Number = t*t2;
        const threeT:Number = 3*t;
        const threeT2:Number = 3*t2;
        result.x = getPointAxisAt(anchor1.x, anchor2.x, control1.x, control2.x, t3, threeT, threeT2);
        result.y = getPointAxisAt(anchor1.y, anchor2.y, control1.y, control2.y, t3, threeT, threeT2);
        result.z = getPointAxisAt(anchor1.z, anchor2.z, control1.z, control2.z, t3, threeT, threeT2);
        return result;
    }
    public function getPointAxisAt(a1:Number,a2:Number,c1:Number,c2:Number, t3:Number, threeT:Number, threeT2:Number):Number {
        return  t3      * (a2+3*(c1-c2)-a1) +
                threeT2 * (a1-2*c1+c2) +
                threeT  * (c1-a1) +
                a1;
    }

    /**
     * @param t
     * @return Un-normalized Vector3D! 
     */
    public function getDirectionAt(t:Number):Vector3D {
        const threeT2:Number = 3 * t * t;
        const sixT:Number = 6 * t;
        result.x = getDirAxisAt(anchor1.x, anchor2.x, control1.x, control2.x, threeT2, sixT);
        result.y = getDirAxisAt(anchor1.y, anchor2.y, control1.y, control2.y, threeT2, sixT);
        result.z = getDirAxisAt(anchor1.z, anchor2.z, control1.z, control2.z, threeT2, sixT);
        return result;
    }
    public function getDirAxisAt(a1:Number,a2:Number,c1:Number,c2:Number, threeT2:Number, sixT:Number):Number {
        return  threeT2 * (a2+3*(c1-c2)-a1) +
                sixT    * (a1-2*c1+c2) +
                3       * (c1-a1);
    }

    public function getDirectionDerivativeAt(t:Number):Vector3D {
        const sixT:Number = 6 * t;
        result.x = getDirDerAxisAt(anchor1.x, anchor2.x, control1.x, control2.x, sixT);
        result.y = getDirDerAxisAt(anchor1.y, anchor2.y, control1.y, control2.y, sixT);
        result.z = getDirDerAxisAt(anchor1.z, anchor2.z, control1.z, control2.z, sixT);
        return result;
    }
    public function getDirDerAxisAt(a1:Number,a2:Number,c1:Number,c2:Number, sixT:Number):Number {
        return  sixT    * (a2+3*(c1-c2)-a1) +
                6       * (a1-2*c1+c2);
    }

    /**
     * Call this after any change to defining points and before accessing normalized points of curve.
     */
    public function recalc():void {
        arcLengths.length = steps + 1;
        arcLengths[0] = 0;
        const step:Number = 1 / steps;

        previous.copyFrom(getPointAt(0));
        _length = 0;
        for (var i:int = 1; i <= steps; ++i) {
            _length += Vector3D.distance(getPointAt(i * step), previous);
            arcLengths[i] = _length;
            previous.copyFrom(result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 'recalc' must have already been called if any changes were made to any of the defining points 
     * @param u
     * @return u normalized/converted to t
     */
    public function normalizeT(u:Number):Number {
        var targetLength:Number = u * arcLengths[steps];
        var low:int = 0,
            high:int = steps,
            index:int; // TODO : have a look-up table of starting low/high indices for each step!
        while (low < high) {
            index = low + ((high - low) >>> 1);
            if (arcLengths[index] < targetLength) {
                low = index + 1;
            } else {
                high = index;
            }
        }
        if (this.arcLengths[index] > targetLength) {
            --index;
        }
        var lengthBefore:Number = arcLengths[index];
        if (lengthBefore === targetLength) {
            return index / steps;
        } else {
            return (index + (targetLength - lengthBefore) / (arcLengths[index + 1] - lengthBefore)) / steps;
        }
    }

    public function getNormalizedPointAt(u:Number):Vector3D {
        return getPointAt(normalizeT(u));
    }

    /**
     * "Normalized" goes for t, not the return Vector3D!!! 
     * @param u
     * @return Un-normalized Vector3D!
     */
    public function getNormalizedDirectionAt(u:Number):Vector3D {
        return getDirectionAt(normalizeT(u));
    }

    public function getNormalizedDirectionDerivativeAt(u:Number):Vector3D {
        return getDirectionDerivativeAt(normalizeT(u));
    }

    public function get length():Number
    {
        return _length;
    }

}
}
```

And here is the code that applies the 2nd degree derivative orientation to the car's wheels:

```
            const dirDer:Vector3D = bezier.getDirectionDerivativeAt(time);
            dirDer.negate(); // negate vector's values; for some reason, this gives better results
            for each (wheel in dirWheels) {
                wheel.setRotation(0,0,0); // must nullify before below line
                const localDirDer:Vector3D = wheel.globalToLocalVector(dirDer); // convert dirDer vector to wheel's local axis; wheel translation does NOT affect conversion
                wheel.setOrientation(localDirDer); // orients the object in a specific direction; Up-vector's default value = (0,1,0) 
            }
```

I even tried (to no avail):

```
            for each (wheel in dirWheels) {
                const localDirDer:Vector3D = wheel.parent.globalToLocalVector(dirDer); // convert dirDer vector to wheel's local axis; wheel translation does NOT affect conversion
                wheel.setOrientation(localDirDer); // orients the object in a specific direction; Up-vector's default value = (0,1,0) 
            }
```

One clear example that something is wrong: even when the car is on a straight line, the wheel originally is non-rotated (as it should), but after the car passes the center point of the line, the wheel rotates 180 degrees!
[image: 1st OK]
[image: 2nd wrong]

**EDIT:**
Here is an example where the Bezier is *degenerated* to a straight line (all 4 points belonging to a straight line)! Since, in the case of a straight line, the direction f'(t) is constant, shouldn't its derivative f''(t) be *always zero*?

For example, for anchor1, anchor2, control1, control2 respectively:

```
Vector3D(-4.01,0.00,-1.90) Vector3D(4.01,0.00,-1.90)
Vector3D(-2.01,0.00,-1.90) Vector3D(2.01,0.00,-1.90)
```

I get

> ```
> f'(0.08)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.08)=Vector3D(10.14,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.11)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.11)=Vector3D(9.42,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.15)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.15)=Vector3D(8.44,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.18)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.18)=Vector3D(7.69,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.21)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.21)=Vector3D(6.87,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.24)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.24)=Vector3D(6.16,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.27)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.27)=Vector3D(5.47,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.30)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.30)=Vector3D(4.70,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.33)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.33)=Vector3D(4.03,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.36)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.36)=Vector3D(3.37,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.39)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.39)=Vector3D(2.63,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.42)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.42)=Vector3D(1.99,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.44)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.44)=Vector3D(1.34,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.47)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.47)=Vector3D(0.62,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.50)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.50)=Vector3D(-0.02,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.53)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.53)=Vector3D(-0.74,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.56)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.56)=Vector3D(-1.38,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.58)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.58)=Vector3D(-2.03,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.61)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.61)=Vector3D(-2.67,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.64)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.64)=Vector3D(-3.41,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.67)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.67)=Vector3D(-4.07,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.70)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.70)=Vector3D(-4.74,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.73)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.73)=Vector3D(-5.51,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.76)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.76)=Vector3D(-6.20,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.79)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.79)=Vector3D(-6.91,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.82)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.82)=Vector3D(-7.74,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.85)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.85)=Vector3D(-8.49,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.89)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.89)=Vector3D(-9.27,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.92)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.92)=Vector3D(-10.19,0.00,0.00)
> f'(0.96)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(0.96)=Vector3D(-11.06,0.00,0.00)
> f'(1.00)=Vector3D(-1.00,0.00,0.00) f''(1.00)=Vector3D(-11.98,0.00,0.00)
> ```

Comment: Normally, we would not use 2nd derivative vector of a path to align objects. We either use path's tangent (i.e., the unitized first derivative vector) or path's normal direction (which is derived from both first derivative and 2nd derivative).

Comment: I use 1st derivative to orient the car and, yes, it works a treat. Obviously I can't use it for the tyres too at the same time. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: From your codes and the picture, it is unclear to me how you define the "wheel orientation". But if I am in your position, I will use the path's normal to define the wheel's orientation. If you consider the wheel as a cylinder capped by two planar faces, then the path's normal will be perpendicular to the two planar faces.

Comment: The wheel orientation is set by the 3D engine I am using: *public function setOrientation(dir:Vector3D, up:Vector3D = (0,1,0)):void;* where (dir:Vector3D = Direction set for orientation). I consider the wheel as you say. Can you give a link of a *path's normal*? All I get in Google is the path's direction (1st derivative, which I already use to orient the car)

Comment: Compute binormal vector b= unit_vector( C' x C") where C' and C" are the first and second derivative vectors of the path C(t). Then, compute normal vector n=b x t where t is the unit tangent vector and 'x' is the cross product operation.

Comment: So, *unit_vector* is a vector-normalization function, and in *n=b x t*, t = unit_vector(C'), right?

Comment: what are the straight line coordinates, and what are the derivatives you see at t=0, t=yourpoint and t=1 for the example you show where things go wrong? As a comment on using the normal: there is no difference between aligning the axle to the normal, or wheel to the derivative. If one works, the other should work, too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Added values for you to see exactly what is going wrong. At t=0.5 f''(t) changes sign, but I don't see why it shouldn't be 0 all the time! Please elaborate a bit on using the "normal". I would really love a couple of answers than a long list of comments!!!

Comment: cubic curves are 3rd order polynomials, so the derivatives (for each dimension) is a quadratic curve, the second derivative is a straight line, and the third derivative is a scalar constant. Even though the cubic curve is a straight line, the *formula* for it is a 3rd order polynomial, and the derivative is three quadratic polynomials that (should) be the same for all `t` values. As a cubic Bezier, the derivative will actually be larger at the end points, but orientation should be preserved... let me check what it *should* be.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You might want to take a look here, the functions are much easier to read with mathematic notation:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250070/what-does-the-2nd-degree-derivative-of-a-cubic-bezier-curve-actually-represent

Comment: I left you an answer there, but for the record we're not interested in the second derivative. We only care about the first. That said, your second derivative numbers are correct so it stands to reason your first derivative numbers would be correct too. If you're using these second derivative numbers, that explains why you're seeing a flip at `t=0.5`, since that's where the acceleration changes sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle of the wheels relative to the direction of the car is related to the **signed curvature** of the path, usually denoted by `\kappa`. For arc-length parameterized curves, `|\kappa| = length of vector dT/ds` where `T` is the unit tangent vector and `dT/ds` is its derivative with respect to the arc length parameter. The sign of `\kappa` depends on the orientation of the curve, but once you've figured out whether left or right is positive at one location, you should be good for the rest of the scenario.

Bezier curves are not arc-length parameterized (unless you have done something ultra-magical), so you'll have to use a more complicated expression. For a path on the plane you should use `\kappa = (x'y''-y'x'')/(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}`. That's nice because you don't need arc length parameterization and also it's signed, but you still have to figure out which sign means left or right.

You also have to figure out the relationship between the angle of the wheels and the curvature. For that, you might find formulas based on the **radius of curvature** `R = 1/\kappa`. The radius of curvature has a nice geometrical meaning (related to the "osculating circle" of the path), but it becomes infinite when the path is a straight line.

Here's one *approximate* formula I found in physics literature for the relationship between wheel angle and radius of curvature: `R = s/sqrt(2-2cos(2A))` where `s` is the wheel base (distance between the centers of the front and rear wheels) and `A` is the angle of the wheels.  You can solve that formula for `A` like so: `(s/R)^2/2 = 1-cos(2A)`, `(s/(2R))^2 = sin^2(A)`, `s\kappa/2 = sin(A)`, `A = arcsin(s\kappa/2)`. That nicely avoids the singularity at 0 angle. As usual, you'll have to check whether the sign makes sense and reverse it if necessary.

Another formula I've seen is `A=arcsin(s\kappa)`. Clearly both formulas can't be right. I'm not sure which one is right. Just try them both, or find a good treatment in the physics literature.

One more thing you have to think about: at what point along the car to measure the curvature. Again, there are (at least) two choices, at front wheel or at back wheels, and I'm not sure which is right. I think back wheels.

If none of those choices works out, I've probably made a mistake. Let me know and I'll check my work.